# Facebook graph api and nested query

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get Friendlist details using Facebook iOS SDK using the below query:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
            [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=id,name,friendlists&fields=id,name,members&fields=pic,can_post,id,link,name,pic_crop,pic_large,pic_small,pic_square,profile_type,username,picture,list_type" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id user, NSError *error) {

            }];
```

I know the mistake is in using the '&' while constructing the query but I am not knowing how to nest the query (to get details like pic, can_post, etc).

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this

```
me?fields=name,about,accounts.fields(about)
```

if you'd like to request 'user' (include name, about) and account connection (include 'about' field)

2nd connection you must user . (dot notation) instead of ?fields=

Answer (score 1):

You should use `+ startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:(FBRequestHandler)handler`:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id user, NSError *error) {

        }];
}
```

Note that it would get all the fields from your friends. If you want only a few ones, you can use `startWithGraphPath:completion:` with `@"me/friends?fields=id,name,pic_square` as graph path.